# Append use in swift

Tags: swift, append

Why the code bellow does not change the string?

```
class Person {

var name = "Chris"
var age = 12
var male = true
var details, = [true, 100 , "good"]

}
family().details.append("friendly")

family().details //prints [1, 100, "good"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're accessing two different objects:

```
family().me.append("friendly")
```

This line creates an object, appending "friendly" to your `[Any]`

```
family().me //prints [1, 100, "good"]
```

Here you're printing the contents of a brand new object: me contains only 3 elements

If you want to see the change use the same object like so:

```swift
let f = family()

f.me.append("friendly")
f.me
```